# Matlab Nested parfor loop , variable cannot be classified

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run the below code but get an error message:

> The variable R in a parfor cannot be classified

Any way to solve it?

```
R=zeros(M,N,Us,Vs,'single');
parfor indM=1:M   
    for indN=1:N
        for indv=1:Vs           
           temp=squeeze(X(indM,indN,:,indv));          
           if(sum(temp(:)~=0))
             R(indM,indN,:,indv)= FractionalFFT_mid0(temp,a);    
           end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @PavelOganesyan: I don't see a duplicate to that question as each worker only accesses the `(indM,:,:,:)` slice.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan - That is not the right duplicate.  The one by Daniel is the correct one, which I have selected to be the final duplicate.

Comment: @rayryeng: I don't see the other questions as duplicates. Here, we have the very simple case of not slicing along the last dimension, whereas the other dupes were about more complex issues. Consequently, I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Matlab require that the parfor-sliced index is the last one (newer versions, e.g. 2014b no longer have the requirements).

```
R=zeros(N,Us,Vs,M,'single');
parfor indM=1:M   
    for indN=1:N
        for indv=1:Vs           
           temp=squeeze(X(indM,indN,:,indv));          
           if(sum(temp(:)~=0))
             R(indN,:,indv,indM)= FractionalFFT_mid0(temp,a);    
           end
        end
    end
end

%# get R back the way you wanted originally
R = permute(R,[4 1 2 3]);
```

Comment: Hm, I don't *think* there ever was such a requirement - I just tried R2007b (the first version with `parfor` in mostly its current form - R2007a and prior releases had a completely different `parfor`...), and the following: `x = zeros(4); parfor (idx = 1:4), x(idx,1) = 7, end` worked as I expected. There have definitely been some changes in what's supported in terms of nested FOR loops though.

Comment: Having said that, I don't know why re-ordering the subscripts makes that work.

Comment: @Edric: The OP's example does work (with some random data) for me in R2014b, but in the past, re-ordering of index variables has helped. I do not remember where I saw it in the documentation, or whether I found it out via trial and error; parfor did use to be a bit iffy at times.